# enable caching of images specifying a modified date

Tags: java, image, jsp, caching, blob

I've a jsp page which loads many images. I'd like to cache the images for faster loading.

I'll explain my idea, please correct it if it's wrong. I'm calling the picture loading servlet for each image and return as a BLOB. My idea is to add a modified date with the image and the other values like Last-Modified, expires, Cache-control and max age. And thereby make the browser understand if the image changes.

But how can i append a modified date to a BLOB? Or is there some better ideas to make them cachable?

Thanks...

Comment: How are the images generated on the server?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Are you asking how to add headers to an HTTP response? Are you asking how to implement the cache?

Comment: Exact duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155276/enable-caching-of-images-specifying-a-modified-date
@Coder247: if you lost your question and/or you'd like to find all your questions, please click at link behind your nickname at the top bar to access your profile: http://stackoverflow.com/users/236112/coder247

Comment: the images are stored as BLOB in oracle. And i retireve it and send it to jsp. Do you think this method is good for caching purpose? 

Or what do you think about my idea like appending a modified to the image and sending it to response with the headers?

Comment: Hi Balus..you are correct. When i posted it, i couldn't see it posted and got a message. It was a mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *I've a jsp page which loads many images. I'd like to cache the images for faster loading.*

This is a Good Thing<sup>TM</sup>.

> *I'll explain my idea, please correct it if it's wrong. I'm calling the picture loading servlet for each image and return as a BLOB. My idea is to add a modified date with the image and the other values like Last-Modified, expires, Cache-control and max age. And thereby make the browser understand if the image changes.*

For that you actually need the [`ETag`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.19), [`Last-Modified`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.29) and optionally also [`Expires`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.21) header. With the `ETag` header both the server and client can identify the unique file. You can if necessary use under each the database key for this. With the `Last-Modified` header header both the server and client knows if they both have the same version of the file. With the `Expires` header you can instruct the client when to re-request the file the firstnext time (thus, when the date as specified in `Expires` has been expired).

The `Cache-Control` header is not so relevant here as you just want to *allow* caching and the average client already does that by default.

For more information and a servlet example, you may find [this article](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/02/fileservlet-supporting-resume-and.html) useful and maybe also [this article](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/09/webapplication-performance-tips-and.html) for the case you'd be interested in tuning performance of a JSP/Servlet webapplication.

> *But how can i append a modified date to a BLOB? Or is there some better ideas to make them cachable?*

Just add one more column to the database table in question which represents the insertion date. In most DB's you can just use `now()` function for this or even create it as an auto-trigger so that it get set automatically on every insert/update.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you should set the appropriate headers for controlled caching.

You can always use the http protocol specs as a reference for sending and setting the appropriate headers (response headers).

You can have a look at the following links:

Caching in HTTP
http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec13.html

Http Protocol Header Field Definitions
http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html

regards,

Answer (score 1):

Don't you want to amend the HTTP headers, rather than the actual image/BLOB itself ?

See [this page](http://www.apl.jhu.edu/~hall/java/Servlet-Tutorial/Servlet-Tutorial-Response-Headers.html) for info on setting headers in the servlet response. I suspect you'll be looking at standard headers such as `Expires`.

Answer (score 1):

(moved from the duplicate question)

Add a filter (`javax.servlet.Filter`) that adds the cache headers whenever the response contains an image. Something like:

```
public class StaticResourceCacheFilter implements Filter {

    public static final String[] CACHEABLE_CONTENT_TYPES = new String[] {
            "text/css", "text/javascript", "image/png", "image/jpeg",
            "image/gif", "image/jpg" };

    static {
        Arrays.sort(CACHEABLE_CONTENT_TYPES);
    }



    public void init(FilterConfig cfg) throws ServletException {

    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {

    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
            FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;


        chain.doFilter(httpRequest, httpResponse);

        String contentType = httpResponse.getContentType();

        if (contentType != null && Arrays.binarySearch(CACHEABLE_CONTENT_TYPES, contentType) > -1) {

            Calendar inTwoMonths = Calendar.getInstance();
            inTwoMonths.add(Calendar.MONTH, 2);

            httpResponse.setHeader("Expires", DateUtil.formatDate(inTwoMonths.getTime()));
        } else {
            httpResponse.setHeader("Expires", "-1");
        }

    }
```

(where `DateUtil` is `org.apache.commons.httpclient.util.DateUtil`)

The above filter, of course, assumes you have set the right `Content-Type` for your images. Otherwise I think they might not be displayed properly in the browser, with or without cache.

To answer your question:

> Is there any way to keep the images in cache until the image get modified in server.

That's a different scenario. You can store your images in some cache implementation ([ehcache](http://ehcache.org/) for example), but this is a server cache, not client cache.